# Como evitar dependências de dependências no Composer?

Tags: composer

Possuo um projeto A que possui uma dependência do projeto B que, por sua vez, possui uma dependência do projeto C.

Então, o gráfico de dependências ficaria assim:

```
A -> B -> C
```

(ps: todos os projetos são desenvolvidos internamente).

No entanto, no composer.json do projeto A, sou obrigado a exigir ambas as dependências:

```
{
    "require": {
        "B": "dev-master",
        "C": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

... enquanto que no projeto B, eu exijo apenas a dependência C:

```
{
    "require": {
        "C": "dev-master"
    }
}
```

Como eu faço para que no projeto A eu exija apenas a dependência B?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi. Eu só consigo fazer o que eu quero referenciando uma tag do projeto, e não ao referenciar `dev-master`:

```
{
    "require": {
        "C": "1.*"
    }
}
```